# how to share image on linkedin from android

Tags: android, linkedin-api

I've integrated the linked in **text** share successfully now i want to share **image with text**,images maybe get either from **sdcard or image URL**. How can i achieve that please provide me some solution.

Here how i shared the linked in text,

```
share.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String share = et.getText().toString();
        if (null != share && !share.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {

            OAuthConsumer consumer = new CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer(Config.LINKEDIN_CONSUMER_KEY, Config.LINKEDIN_CONSUMER_SECRET);
            consumer.setTokenWithSecret(accessToken.getToken(), accessToken.getTokenSecret());

            DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost post = new HttpPost("https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/shares");
            try {
                consumer.sign(post);
            } catch (OAuthMessageSignerException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (OAuthExpectationFailedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (OAuthCommunicationException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } // here need the consumer for sign in for post the share
            post.setHeader("content-type", "text/XML");
            String myEntity = "<share><comment>"+ share +"</comment><visibility><code>anyone</code></visibility></share>";
            try {
                post.setEntity(new StringEntity(myEntity));
                org.apache.http.HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(post);
                Toast.makeText(LinkedInSampleActivity.this,
                        "Shared sucessfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }else {
            Toast.makeText(LinkedInSampleActivity.this,
                    "Please enter the text to share",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
});
}
```

Comment: see this..https://code.google.com/p/socialauth-android/issues/detail?id=41

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply,which means we cant able to share image on LInkedIn?

Comment: yes.,will you upvote my answer.???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see [here](https://code.google.com/p/socialauth-android/issues/detail?id=41)

```
currently socialauth has not provided any facility for posting image on linkedin.
```

Comment: one more doubt can we able to reply for the post

Comment: can u provide me some sample for that

Comment: i want to reply for the particular post message,like twitter reply

Comment: see i am confused what you want.do you want post message on linkedin??

Comment: no i already posted some message on LinkedIn now i want to type reply for that message is it possible

Comment: @user3282586 no i havenot seen any suggetion for this..,sory.

Answer (score 0):

Currently Linkedin does not allow posting images. Instead of image post link.